# C# Making program wait until browser finish loading webpage

Tags: c#, .net

How do i make my program to wait until webpage finish loading before executing next statement. I tried Process::WaitForInputIdle(); but it doesn't wait.

```
ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("firefox.exe");

pInfo.Arguments = "http://example.com";

Process p  = Process.Start(pInfo);

p.WaitForInputIdle();

pInfo.Arguments = "http://example.net";

p = Process.Start(pInfo);

p.WaitForInputIdle();
```

Comment: what you want to do using `firefox` as a process.. you may use `WebBrowserConrtol` or `WebClient` these controls have many events..`WebbrowserControl` will solve your issue

Comment: My app will work only in firefox .. :) ...Is there any other way

Comment: Your best bet then is to fix your app to work in all browsers. What Firefox specific functionality do you use that other browsers don't manage to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The problem here is that Firefox does not communicate back when the web page has loaded. You will for example see issues when Firefox wants to update itself before it opens the web page. How is it going to communicate back when the page is loaded? In between, the entire firefox.exe executable has been replaced, and the connection with your `Process` has been long lost.

The `WaitForInputIdle` does a very specific job, and this is not what you expect. Windows works through a message pump. When you e.g. move the mouse over a window, a message is send to that window. `WaitForIdleInput` returns when the application has processed the first message it has received, so when Windows knows it is 'responsive'.