# C#-Wait for IE to load?

Tags: internet-explorer, c#-4.0

I'm opening a URL in a web browser using the following code:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = GetDefaultBrowserPath();  //gets path to default browser from the registry
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "htp://www.google.com";
        p.Start();
```

Can someone tell me how I would wait for IE to be loaded? Is this the correct way to go about this?

Thanks,
Jimmy

Comment: Can you add some more context about your problem? For instance, what are you trying to accomplish that would require waiting for the default browser (not necessarily IE) to be loaded? There might be another way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Brian I need to take a screenshot of the link opened in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

It'll open it in the default browser.

Comment: Marking as answer. I found a duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030163/c-making-program-wait-untill-brower-finish-loading-webpage

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for

```
p.WaitForInputIdle()
```