# When calling two browser windows in NSIS, how to make sure the last one gets focus?

Tags: internet-explorer, focus, uac, nsis, timing

I have this nsis script,

...

```
nsExec::Exec "openFirstWindow.exe"  ;HERE This exe will open a FIRST WINDOW to whatever url

Pop $exe_return_code
StrCmp $exe_return_code "0" exe_success
Goto exe_done
exe_success:
    ;HERE is the call to the SECOND WINDOW
    UAC::Exec '' '"$PROGRAMFILES\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.google.ca"' '' ''

exe_done:
```

...

The problem is that randomly, I get the **FIRST** window in foreground and the **SECOND** behind,
and sometimes I get the **SECOND** window in front of the **FIRST**.

My guess is that it is due to the **FIRST** window taking random time to open and
if the **SECOND** window finishes opening before the **FIRST** one, then the **FIRST** one will get the focus and be on top.

Does anyone have a solution to make sure that the **SECOND** window has focus ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple loop to bring required window in the front. (I used Exec, but works fine with UAC and nsExec)

```
; This Window is opened as first
Exec '"$PROGRAMFILES\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.google.sk"' 
; This is opened later
Exec '"$PROGRAMFILES\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "www.unsigned-softworks.sk/installer"'  

CheckWindow:
  Sleep 500 ; Wait some time (miliseconds)

  ; Find by Window class and by Window name 
  FindWindow $1 "IEFrame" "Google - Windows Internet Explorer" 

  ; If window is not found (not loaded!) search again 
  IntCmp $1 0 CheckWindow Continue Continue

Continue:
  # If found (opened & loaded), bring it to front
  System::Call "User32::SetForegroundWindow(i) b ($1)"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a simple problem, because opening a web page is asynchronous: you don't know when the loading has finished. An elegant solution would be to have a feedback from the browser that the first page has loaded, but it's a lot of work since you'd have to support every browser. By the way you  force the use of IE, it's not a good idea, you should use the user's default browser

Maybe some [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) script can watch and wait for the browser window/tab to open.

Or simply wait for a few seconds between both calls.

***EDIT***

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4030163/11343) [and this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4270062/11343)

Comment: I totally agree that I should not force the use of IE ;) But in that case, it was necessary because this part of the script was for IE users only. I did try to wait few seconds, up to 8 seconds, but for whatever reason, the focus was given back to the FIRST window. I'll take a look into AutoIt script. Thanks.

Comment: Nice post ! I could use a process.start thing to know when it finishes. But I'd like to do it in NSIS if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: @developerGuile Don't know if it's possible in NSIS. Cheers

Comment: I understand I could use C# and make a .dll that I could call through the NSIS but, I always feel like using a .dll is a breach in security ... am I wrong (i could start a whole question about that).